# Is it possible to find a given child class in a list of parent classes in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Given a list of ClassA, populated by several child classes of ClassA (Like ClassB, or ClassC), is there a way to iterate through the list and find instances of ClassB or ClassC and access their class-exclusive methods?

Comment: It is surely possible. Hint: check `as` / `is`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Yes it is.

Comment: You're right. Guess my ability to Google isn't as good as I once thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is. The usual pattern for the code is

```
 ClassB classB = classA as ClassB;
 if (classB == null)
 {
     // do something else, probably return
 }
 classB.DoTheThingYouNeedClassBFor();
```

Though, as an aside, this situation is a bit of a "code smell". Usually, if you find yourself in that situation, there is room for improvement in your design. If you elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve, perhaps someone can suggest a better solution.

Comment: I'm making an entity component system. I need this to implement something similar to Unity3d's GetComponent function. Thank you for your answer but zerkms' comment pointed me in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a list of some non homogeneous classes you can do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new List<A>{
        new A(),
        new B(),
        new C()
    };

    //1
    Console.Write(a.Where(x => x is C).ToList().Count());
}

public class A {
    string a;
}

public class B: A {
    int b;
}

public class C: B {
    long c;
}
```

Comment: Use .OfType() instead of Where() for that sort of filtering